# Has anyone tried to use the hierarchy of ImageNet?

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, reference-request

The classes of [ImagNet](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5206848/) have a hierarchy. Did anybody try to build a hierarchy of classifiers to use this fact?

Searching for "multistage classification" leads to different results.

Comment: Similar, but not quite the same: [Network of Experts for Large-Scale Image Categorization](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-46478-7_32)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, multiple papers have used this. I've heard of multiple ways to exploit this hierarchial structure. This paper [Hierarchical Deep Convolutional Neural Network for Large Scale
Visual Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0736.pdf) uses multiple levels by predicting the more coarse distribution and I think it then passes this as features to the more low level classification. [YOLO9000](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08242) actually uses the ImageNet hierarchy for the problem of object detection. Hierarchial classification is the name of the problem you are describing.